# how to write ID into device via bluetooth 4.0 instead of using USB cable

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was already struggle so hard to find the answer on the internet, but I haven't found any solution yet. My situation is we want to write ID into our device using bluetooth transmission. In our device, we use TI cc2540 chip in our device. We originally used USB cable to write ID into device over serial port, the ID was written by using some function like "serial port.write" into the device.

Now we want to write ID via bluetooth to the same location. I was trying writing ID into GATT profile, but it looked like the location that I wrote into is not the location that was written via USB cable, because when we used our USB cable program to check if the ID was changed, there was no changed actually.

I think I might use the different way to write data into the device and I need to change the way. But I can not figure out how to write data into the same location where the USB cable wrote in.

Comment: I think you are looking for BlueZ.  Do a search on BlueZ sample code.

Comment: I am using bluetooth USB dongle to connect our device, can the BlueZ API control the dongle?

Comment: Yes.  I was able to do exactly that.